# Change ItemSource inside SelectionChanged Event take effect after eventhandler

Tags: c#, wpf

After changing the selection of a combo box I have a collection I want to bind to an ItemsControl.
I would like to access the VisualTree of the ItemsControl within the SelectionChanged Handler. But changing the ItemsSource affects the ItemsControl only after the EventHandler.
Is it possible to access the elements at this time?

```
private void cbShows_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Show selectedShow = (Show)cb.SelectedItem;
        txtShowname.Text = selectedShow.ShowName;

        icHalfHourBlocks.DataContext = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;
        icHalfHourBlocks.ItemsSource = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;

        gridShowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // At this Time need the rendered visual tree //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to do it there? What about using BeginInvoke to execute your action after the visual tree is updated?

Comment: Is there an event that tells me that the visual tree has updated?

Comment: My goal is to focus an itemscontrolitem by property value that is is Not in front of View.

Comment: In the example you have some comment block which replaces your code accessing the visual tree.  If instead of executing it there you wrap that block of code into a BeginInvoke call, then it will automatically get executed AFTER the ItemsControl updates its visual tree in response to changing  the selected item.  You can specify the DispatcherPriority of your BeginInvoke call.

Comment: You mean something like that: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { // Code to access rendered visual tree // }), DispatcherPriority.Render);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to do an action on the dispatcher with BeginInvoke. I have now access to the rendered visual tree and was able to retrieve my searched controls.
This is my Code now:

```
private void cbShows_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Show selectedShow = (Show)cb.SelectedItem;
        txtShowname.Text = selectedShow.ShowName;

        icHalfHourBlocks.DataContext = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;
        icHalfHourBlocks.ItemsSource = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;

        gridShowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            IEnumerable<Expander> elements = FindVisualChildren<Expander>(icHalfHourBlocks).Where(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "HalfHourBlock");
        }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

@RaceRalph thanks for your tip.

**Update:**

I found a better solution this Case. The method UpdateLayout() do the Visual tree Update.

```
private void cbShows_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Show selectedShow = (Show)cb.SelectedItem;
        txtShowname.Text = selectedShow.ShowName;

        icHalfHourBlocks.DataContext = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;
        icHalfHourBlocks.ItemsSource = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;

        IcHalfHourBlocks.UpdateLayout(); // <-- My new solution

        IEnumerable<Expander> elements = FindVisualChildren<Expander>(icHalfHourBlocks)
            .Where(x => x.Tag != null && x.Tag.ToString() == "HalfHourBlock");

        gridShowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...But changing the `ItemsSource` affects the `ItemsControl` only after the EventHandler. Is it possible to access the elements at this time?

You could try to measure and arrange the control in your event handler after you have set the `ItemsSource` and `Visibility` properties:

```
private void cbShows_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cb.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Show selectedShow = (Show)cb.SelectedItem;
        txtShowname.Text = selectedShow.ShowName;

        icHalfHourBlocks.DataContext = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;
        icHalfHourBlocks.ItemsSource = selectedShow.HalfHourItems;

        gridShowGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // At this Time need the rendered visual tree //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ic.Measure(new Size(icHalfHourBlocks.ActualWidth, icHalfHourBlocks.ActualHeight));
        ic.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, icHalfHourBlocks.ActualWidth, icHalfHourBlocks.ActualHeight));
    }
}
```